# How can I put cursor on every line in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to be able to edit every line of my data simultaneously, for instance put quotations in front of every line. I am wondering what the key combination is that will enable me to do this.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Four steps:

1. Select all the text: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Activate multi-cursors: <kbd>CTRL (or CMD on Mac)</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>
3. Press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key to move all cursors to the front of the line
4. Press the <kbd>"</kbd> quote key to insert the quote.

Using the <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>left | right</kbd> arrow keys is handy when managing multiple cursors.

Comment: I've been using sublime for 5+ years, and wish I knew this years ago. @Jacko Give this man the green checkmark.

Comment: how isn't this even checked as the answer

Comment: So sorry folks, I've been out of commission - just gave Eric the green check!

Comment: Feels like I come back here once a month after trying every other key combination I can think of. Thanks (again) for this.

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero how?

Comment: Danger Will Robinson - be warned, if youre using AMD Radeon software and have hotkeys enabled, it will hijack Ctrl-Shift-L and say "Performance Logging Started". Hopefully google will save some sorry souls struggling with this. The answer is to disable hotkeys in the AMD Radeon app.

Comment: This is a great answer, can't imaging how much time it will save me.

Answer (score 17):

On a mac, you can highlight the lines you wish to edit and use <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> on Windows.

Comment: If you happen to use Loom, quit that program because it hijacks this hotkey combo on mac.

Comment: For the loom comment, thank you kindly!!! It drove me nuts!!

Answer (score 13):

### On Mac

1. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Select all)
2. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Split selection into lines)
3. <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (Surround selection with quotes)
4. <kbd>esc</kbd> (Escape)

[image: Multiple cursors]

Comment: Thanks! Step 3 should be shift + ".

Comment: Step 3 is definitely locale dependent

Answer (score 9):

On Windows

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Select all Data)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Cursor will appear on each line)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ (right or left key) (move the cursor left or right)

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to remove the focus.

Comment: Appreciate it Hassan / HMD

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to put cursor at every string as currently selected, use Find All shortcut:

Windows/Linux: Alt+F3

Mac: ⌃+⌘+G

[All Multiple Selection shortcuts](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html)